# navbar profile image not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Top Navbar on my page which lets the user search with a display on their profile image, name and company.

I want the design to look something like below:

[image]

Could anyone point my in the right direction.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #f9fafd;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.input-group-addon {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

nav img {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="input-group mr-auto">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="./assets/images/search-icon.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"/></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for an Application..." />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
      <div style="float: left;">
        <span style="display: block;">User Logged In</span>
        <span>Company Name</span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="http://vvcexpl.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/profile-default-male.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Show us your CSS.

Comment: @Krusader Added. Sorry I forgot to add that.

Comment: How exactly should the different elements be layed out? So the user name and company should be next to the profile image, thats what the red arrow indicates. I don't understand the meaning of the blue arrow.

Comment: @timakro The red arrow shows that the Name and Company should be next to the profile image (Currently its over to the left) and the blue arrow means that Name, Company and the Image should then be put on the same line as the search bar.

Comment: @BenClarke Check My Ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly in terms of placement and positioning, the below code snippet should demonstrate how to achieve your intended end result and steer you in the right direction. I have made no attempt at adjusting any widths as I believe this would be better suited if left up to you.

**Additional CSS Rules Declared:**

```
a.nav-link {
  float: right;
}

a.nav-link>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-group.mr-auto {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Note that inline styles for `float` rules have been removed from for given elements.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #f9fafd;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
}

.input-group-addon {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
}

nav img {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

a.nav-link {
  float: right;
}

a.nav-link>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-group.mr-auto {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="input-group mr-auto">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><img src="./assets/images/search-icon.png" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;"/></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for an Application..." />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">
      <div>
        <span style="display: block;">User Logged In</span>
        <span>Company Name</span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="http://vvcexpl.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/profile-default-male.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is weird as I've added your code and the layout is just completely screwed up, but your example looks right.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span> Company Name </span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span> User LoggedIn </span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span><img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/7c/c7/a6/7cc7a630624d20f7797cb4c8e93c09c1.png" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <div class="input-group  input-sm" style="width: 400px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
     
    </form>
  </div>      
</nav>

<div class="container">
 bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla 
  bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla 
   bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla 
    bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla 
     bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla 
      bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla
       bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla  bla
        bla   bla   bla  bla  bla  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only issue is the User Logged In and Company Name text needs to be next to the image on the left.

Comment: @BenClarke Now Check

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.input-group {
    float: left;
}
```